# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object SparseArray<int[]>

Tags: java, android, serialization, sparse-matrix

So I wanted to send in the Bundle a SparseArray but since it can't I made a class to make the SparseArray into an Serializable object, but now when I run my application it gives this error output.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.awemobi.legominifigures.DataHelper)
```

The class giving this issue is the next one:

```
public class DataHelper implements Serializable {
private SparseArray<int[]> data;

public DataHelper(SparseArray<int[]> data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

public SparseArray<int[]> getArray()
{
    return  data;
}
```

}

I thought it could be because of the int[] and I even made another class Positions to make int[] serializable but the problem persists. What can I try to do more? I can't trace exactly what might be the cause of the error.

This is the complete output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.awemobi.legominifigures, PID: 18077
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.awemobi.legominifigures.DataHelper)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1388)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1335)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:137)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1191)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:384)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1357)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1262)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2944)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3355)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.util.SparseArray
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1383)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1335) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:137) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1191) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:384) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1357) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1262) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663) 
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2944) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3355) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Comment: Stack trace please.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm not sure what do you mean with stack trace. Could your explain me please? I've searched already, but still not sure what it is.

Comment: The stack trace is the thing with the exception and error message the top. This is Java 101.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my post with that information. I suspected it was that, but since I never called it stack trace I was not sure, thanks for understanding and explained.

Comment: OK, so what part of `java.io.NotSerializableException: android.util.SparseArray` don't you understand?

Comment: I found posts telling to implement Serializable, but that's what I'm doing in my DataHelper class and it still complains about NotSerializable. 

For some people it worked making a class Serializable that included the SparseArray and passing it in the bundle, but I'm getting this error, do I need to implement Parcelable too?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your SparseArray variable "data" as transient, like this,

```
private transient SparseArray<int[]> data;
```